# Is there a way to config coredns kubernetes plugin with kubeconfig in token?

Tags: kubernetes, coredns

My coredns in k8s cluster is v1.3.1.And I want to config it visiting kube-apiserver with static token.
For example,my token is "token4K8sSecure".Ant I tried config coredns kubenernetes plugin with the configuration below.But it does not work.

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
           **endpoint https://100.6.0.20:6443
           kubeconfig token token4K8sSecure**
           pods insecure
           upstream
           fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
           ttl 30
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2019-11-19T08:55:08Z"
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "452688"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/coredns
  uid: 449a38b9-1678-4c66-b1e8-96b5c273ad3d
```

Output:
[root@a2 Matrix-V500R002B01D001]# kubectl logs coredns-7c4665f97b-nh2wj -n kube-system
plugin/kubernetes: stat token: no such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to StackOverflow.

You can - instead of using a Kubernetes Token - you can use Client Certificates like so:

```
tls <PATH_TO_CERT> <PATH_TO_KEY> <PATH_TO_CACERT>
```

If you don't want to use TLS Certificates you can specify a File as the `kubeconfig`, with version *1.2.2* CoreDNS introduced the possibility that you can use a File from which CoreDNS loads the Context:

```
kubeconfig /path/to/token token
```

Mount the token into the Container and add the Path to the Config and it should work.

Comment: **Thanks for your answer!**coredns has a token which is already mounted to the pod,I tried use it with config:"kubeconfig /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token token",but failed in log:"Error loading config file "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token": couldn't get version/kind;".Because the token file is a pure string not a json structure.And I don't want to change coredns yaml.

Comment: Without changing the CoreDNS Deployment you can not do what you want. There is no option in CoreDNS where you can define the Token as "plaintext".

Comment: @Miro can you please mark the Answer as "Correct Answer" so other people who are searching for the same problem can find it directly or do you have any other Questions/ Troubles with me answer?